# How to use SecPKCS12Import with private key encrypted with AES_256

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, encryption, openssl

I am generating a PKCS12 file using OpenSSL library in Swift. Following is the code that I use to generate the file:

```
guard let p12 = PKCS12_create(passPhrase, name, privateKey, certificate, nil, NID_aes_256_cbc, 0, 0, 0, 0) else {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr)
        return
    }
```

Please note that I am using NID_aes_256_cbc to encrypt the private key.

Then when I use the following code to import the p12 file in swift, I had the error code of -26275.

```
var items: CFArray?
    let certOptions: NSDictionary = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString: passwordStr as NSString]
    self.securityError = SecPKCS12Import(p12Data as NSData, certOptions, &items)
    print(securityError!.description)
```

After consulting [OSStatus](https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-26275) for error code explanation, I found that it's a `errSecInvalidKey`.

If I change the parameter from `NID_aes_256_cbc` back to `0`, which uses the default 3DES algorithm, everything works fine.

So I was wondering if `SecPKCS12Import` decrypting the private key with 3DES algorithm by default. If yes, how should I make `SecPKCS12Import` to decrypt the AES encrypted private key?